# Android: ImageView scaleType, fitXy Doesn't Work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I used the below code, in the layout. I used the scale type property  and set it to "fitXy", to stretch the src image to fill the ImageView. But it doesn't work and the source image is not stretched to fill the full imageview size. I'm an absolute beginner in android and please help me with this.

Below, is the code i used.

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_calander"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_new_exam"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
     <!-- some more code -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Update your layout like this

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#ff00" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_new_exam"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

You had given margin

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```